# Adding shapefile to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, coordinate-system, export

I attached the link to the .shp files at the bottom.

Ive been exporting .shp files via Pathfinder Office. Every time I export this file it either exports in the middle of Atlantic or somewhere in the middle of Ohio. I am working in southern PA.

In Arc Map, I add new base map. Save the projection-WGS_1984Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere.
From there I export my data from terrasync to PFO run the dif cor. and export it to a .esri shapefile. when I export the .shp file I make sure to select properties and browse to the projection file I just saved.

If I can get past this step. I need to use the kriging tool to add colors to all 5000 points I logged. I would like to have a key something like

Green  0-12000
Yellow 12001-18000 
Red    18001-100000

Ive done quite a bit of research on kriging but there is several different tools to use and im not sure which one to use.

https://sites.google.com/site/strubegps/kmlfiles

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  The best way to get quick and comprehensive answers here is to keep editing your question to make what is being asked ever clearer as people ask for clarifications via comments.

Comment: Your shapefiles are not complete... a "shapefile" is [actually a set of files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Shapefile_file_extensions/005600000003000000/).

Comment: At the moment you have a second question about kriging that you may find distracts potential answerers to your first and presumably more important question at this stage. My advice would be to edit that out and research/ask about it separately.

Comment: Following on Dan's answer, it sounds like you have surveyed points with a GPS unit. That is where you'll find the coordinates your data was collected in, assuming the equipment was set up correctly. Depending on the type of unit and setup, that may be a known CRS or a completely custom local one. With proper setup I would expect the Terrasync/Pathfinder process would have correctly defined a CRS and given a .prj as part of its output, so the problem may be earlier in the process than we can help with. And as Erica's answer mentions, if you *just* want to symbolize points Kriging isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the shapefile/projection problem solved:

[Kriging is a method of interpolating points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Kriging_works/009z00000076000000/) to create a continuous surface.

I think that you actually want to use [graduated colors](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000029000000) to modify the symbology of the points, manually setting classification breaks at the values you need.